# How do I use the new interface function names in Delphi 11's Androidapi.JNI.Support?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

In my Delphi Android service I have this code:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.Support;
var
  ncb: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
begin
 {$if COMPILERVERSION > 32}
    ncb := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(
      TAndroidHelper.Context,
      StringToJString(CHANNEL_ID)
      );
 {$endif}
```

So I think, ok, lets open this code in the Delphi 11 IDE and try to compile.

After a lot of error messages, a bit of fiddling and looking at the new `Androidapi.JNI.Support.pas`, I end up with

```
var
  {$if COMPILERVERSION > 34}
  ncb: Japp_NotificationCompat_Builder;
  {$else}
  ncb: JNotificationCompat_Builder;
  {$endif}
begin
 {$if COMPILERVERSION > 34}
 ncb := Japp_NotificationCompat_Builder.???

 {$else}
 ncb := TJNotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(
   TAndroidHelper.Context,
   StringToJString(CHANNEL_ID)
   );
 {$endif}
```

But now I'm stuck. There doesn't seem to be a way to do the same thing with `Japp_NotificationCompat_Builder` in Delphi 11 as I did with `TJNotificationCompat_Builder` in Delphi 10.3.3 and 10.4.

What am I missing?

Comment: The whole `Androidapi.JNI.Support` unit is just one big mess in general in Delphi 11: [RSP-35008: Inconsistent naming in Androidapi.JNI.Support](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-35008)

Comment: You forgot the `T` when constructing the instance. It is `TJapp_NotificationCompat_Builder.JavaClass.init(...`

Comment: Thanks @DalijaPrasnikar, it's been one of those days! Nevertheless, I'm happy that my question makes others aware of the naming changes.